# Can I use Basic authentication in website and Token authentication in web Api, Is this wrong concept?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a website in asp.net, where user registrations required and also need to create a WebApi code for mobile app users.

Currently user registration is created in asp.net Webform, and login works fine(used basic authenication), but when I tries to login using WebApi code
it shows error 400 bad request(token based authentication), all parameters passed are correct.

Is this happens because I used basic authentication in Webform ?
Do I need to use basic authentication in WebApi also? if yes then how does it work for login?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same authentication model for both use cases. So to implement basic authentication in WebApi there is [a good article from Mike Wasson](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters). You can find the source code [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/BasicAuthentication/Filters/BasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs). It's too much to copy it here.

Create your own `[BasicAuthentication]` Attribute and add it to your controller classes. I would not use cookies, instead send your credentials every time you call the Api within the Authentication-Header of your HTTP call. But make sure you use **HTTPS**!

And to answer your question about mobile apps: Yes of course, adding an authentication header is possible within any mobile application. Same advice here about using HTTPS...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same basic auth for webapi that you use for webforms (both cookie based).

Comment: Using basic auth in web api will work fine with mobile app, right?